# controller input validation in mvc api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

i have built an api and need to validate input objects passed as parameters to controller actions.
Sometimes the same input class will have differing compulsory properties for different actions.

so

```
public class test
{
public ActionResult Create(User user)
{
  //here user_name must be present but no user_id
}
public ActionResult Delete(User user)
{
  //here only user_id must be present.
}
}
```

I have had a look at fluentValidation.net but it seems one has to create rules on a per class basis not class/action.

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just make `Delete` take only an ID?

Comment: You could use different view models for your controllers that only include the properties required to complete your actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is a `User`?

I don't mean in the sense of where is the class defined, but in the sense of what does it physically mean in the domain?  It sounds like you're trying to get it to mean multiple things.

Instead of trying to fit these actions into a model for the domain, create action models for them.  Something like this:

```
class CreateUserAction
{
  public string Username {get; set;}
}

class DeleteUserAction
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
}
```

Then use these in your action methods:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserAction user)
{
}

public ActionResult Delete(DeleteUserAction user)
{
}
```

This will break out the different purposes into different classes, in accordance with the single responsibility principle.  Now the `User` class can focus on simply representing a user object, as opposed to *sometimes* representing a not-yet-created user or *sometimes* representing only the ID of a user object, etc.

One major benefit here is that you can specify the validation rules directly in the class.  With this approach, a `User` object can *always* require a `Username` *and* an `ID` to be valid.  Whereas a `CreateUserAction` object doesn't even have an `ID` (since it doesn't need one) and a `DeleteUserAction` object doesn't have a `Username` (since it doesn't need one).

You can further add additional fields as needed.  For example, the `CreateUserAction` object will likely have other fields to describe the user being created.  (It may even have fields that don't go on a `User` object at all, but would be translated into some other object in the domain.)  However, the `DeleteUserAction` may never need anything more than an `ID` (and, as suggested by SLaks, can probably be replaced with just an `int` for that action method, but that's up to you).

Clearer roles and responsibilities for classes, fewer partially-initialized half-objects.

Comment: thanks. i have ended up doing something along these lines.
except using inheritance and an empty child class on which I place all fluent rules
public class User
{
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public class myUser : User{}
   public class myUser Validator : AbstractValidator<myUser >
    {
    //rules 
}

have a problem no of how to serialise to the base type though.