# cast child type as base/parent type for serialisation

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am using a child type with no properties in order to place fluent validation rules on the object when it is being used in a particular way.

so

```
public class User
{
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public class myUser : User{}
```

However when the object gets to my serialiser I want it to serialise it to the base type. so 'User' is the root element not 'myUser'.

Comment: I don't understand. How does a type that inherits all members from the base type help you with fluent validation rules?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068134/controller-input-validation-in-mvc-api/9068366#9068366

Comment: But that doesn't say anything about inheritance. In fact, if `User` is the type that has all the properties, then `myUser` is useless for this kind of validation, because members from base type can't be removed in derived type. What purpose does `myUser` serve that can't be fulfilled just by using `User`?

Comment: fluentvalidation requires you to create rules per class. I want to pass user as an input param to different controller actions. The createUser action requires different members to the deleteuser action. So i create two child classes where the rules are defined. the actions expect the child classes. However once the validation is complete i want to cast it back to the parent as this is what the xml serialiser expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Why not simply cast it back to User before doing the serialization?</strike>

After doing some digging around in the XmlSerializer, this does it for me:

```
var myUser = new myUser();
myUser.Name = "Test name";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User), new Type[] {myUser.GetType()});
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, myUser);
```

What is being done here is creating an `XmlSerializer` with the base type (User in this case) you want to cast into, as well as an array of other types that you want to allow. These types have to be derived from the base type, it would seem.

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<User xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org 2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="myUser">
  <Name>Test name</Name>
</User>
```

Note the `xsi:type="myUser"`, not sure if this will cause a problem for your deserialization process.

Comment: i tried this. It doesnt work, the instance remain a child type.

Comment: This is interesting and I apologize for giving an incorrect answer. Looking forward to a proper answer regarding this.

Comment: Updated my answer with something that might actually work. :)

Comment: Instead of `new User().GetType()`, it's much better to write just `typeof(User)`.